# Splitting Python Integer(blender3d)

Tags: python, arrays, split, int, separator

This sounds very simple but is it possible to split an integer like lets say 8 to an array like this [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] 
 i have already tried the code below

```
proxies= 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h'#list of objects to attach the expression to 
objlist = proxies.split(",")#splits every word as an object wherever theres a comma ,

ofset = (len(objlist))
```

ofset comes out as 8. but i want ofset  to be an array of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change :

```
ofset = (len(objlist))
```

to :

```
ofset = range(len(objlist)+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list(range(8+1))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Don't forget the `+1`.

Comment: or just `range(len(objlist)+1)` if using python 2

Comment: Even in Python 3, a `range()` object will work in many contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `range`

```
>>> range(len(objlist)+1)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this, you will have index and value side by side:

```
>>> proxies= 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h'
>>> for i,x in enumerate(proxies.split(',')):
...     print i,x
... 
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
5 f
6 g
7 h
```

if you want only range

```
>>>range(0,len(proxies.split(','))+1)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another cool way. You don't have to use the split() function.

```
proxies= set('abcdefgh')# the set() splits the characters into set proxies
objlist= list(proxies)# proxies is converted into a list
ofset = list(range(len(objlist)+1))
```